# Docker + Nodejs Getting Error: Cannot find module "for a module that I wrote"

Tags: node.js, docker

I am Docker beginner.
I was able to implement docker for my nodejs project, but when I try to pull it I am getting the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'my_db'
```

(my_db is a module that I wrote that handles my mysql functionality).

So I am guessing my modules are not bundled into the docker image, right?
I moved my modules to a folder name my_node_modules/ so they won't be ignored.
I also modified the Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM node:11.10.1
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./my_node_modules/*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node index.js
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this `mv node_modules ../`? and how are you including your module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. First create a `.dockerignore`:

```
.git
node_modules
```

The above ensures that the `node_modules` folder is excluded from the actual build context.

You should add any temporary things to your `.dockerignore`. This will also speed up the actual build, since the build context will be smaller.

In my docker file I would then first only copy `package.json` and any existing lock file in order to be able to cache this layer:

```
FROM node:11.10.1
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Only copy package* before installing to make better use of cache
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install --production --silent
# Copy everything
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node index.js
```

Like I also wrote in my comment, I have no idea why you are doing this `mv node_modules ../`? This will move the `node_modules` directory out from the `/usr/src/app` folder, which is **not** what you want.

It would also be nice to see how you are actually including your module.

If you own module resides in the following folder `my_node_modules/my_db` it will be copied when doing `COPY . .` in the above docker file. Then in your `index.js` file you should be able to use the module like this:

```
const db = require('./my_node_modules/my_db');
```

Comment: @YanivN - So, what was the problem? Please tell us a little bit of what solved your problem, since it might help others in the future =)

Comment: Sure! The solution removes line:
    `COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./my_node_modules/*", "./"]`

and modifies line from:
    `RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../`
To
    `RUN npm install --production --silent`

Answer (score 0):

`COPY . .` this step will override everything in the current directory and copying node modules from Host is not recommended and maybe it breaks the container in case of host biners compiled for Window and you are using Linux container.

So better to refactor your Dockerfile and install modules inside docker instead of copying from the host.

```
FROM node:11.10.1
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --production --silent
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node index.js
```

Also will suggest using `.dockerignore`

```
# add git-ignore syntax here of things you don't want copied into docker image

.git
*Dockerfile*
*docker-compose*
node_modules
```

Comment: Usually in docker you want to make the best use of the cache. With this Dockerfile you end up to redownload everything every time a change is done in the code even if it's unrelated to the package.json. IMHO you should only keep the `.dockerignore` part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Stefano, Then better to use mounting if there is frequent change, as he doing it for production so better to build fresh image